# Swift - Firebase Getting a Facebook Friends UID in Firestore

Tags: swift, facebook, firebase, facebook-graph-api, google-cloud-firestore

For a little background - I have a 'Follow Facebook Friends' ViewController where users can view their friends who also have downloaded my app to follow on the app.

I have correctly called the FBSDK to get a list of friends that have also downloaded the app, but now I need to get these friends uid's in Firebase so I can follow/unfollow them accordingly.

Currently, when I get a FB users id - I get the numeric string as mentioned in the facebook documentation.  However, the users uid in Firebase is different.  Is there a way to find which firebase user correlates with a FB id?  Or should I try to store a Facebook User by facebook id in firebase?

```
    var facebookContacts = [User]()

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "facebookContactCell", for: indexPath) as! FacebookContactCell

    // Configure the cell...
    let user = facebookContacts[indexPath.row]

    cell.contactNameLabel.text = user.name
    cell.userId = user.documentId
    // Set follow button state
    if followingArray.contains(cell.userId) {
        cell.followButton.isSelected = true
    } else {
        cell.followButton.isSelected = false
    }

    let userImageRef = storage.child("userImages/"+(user.documentId)+"/profile_pic.jpg")
    // Download in memory with a maximum allowed size of 1MB (1 * 1024 * 1024 bytes)
    userImageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
        if let error = error {
            // Uh-oh, an error occurred! Display Default image
            print("Error - unable to download image: \(error)")
            cell.contactImageView.image = UIImage(named: "userProfileGray")
        } else {
            // Data for "locationImages/(locationId).jpg" is returned
            cell.contactImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        }
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
    }

    return cell
}

    func getFbFriends() {
    let params = ["fields": "id, first_name, last_name, name, email, picture"]

    let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me/friends", parameters: params)
    let connection = FBSDKGraphRequestConnection()
    connection.add(graphRequest, completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) in
        if error == nil {
            let resultdict = result as! NSDictionary
            print("Result Dict: \(resultdict)")

            let data : NSArray = resultdict.object(forKey: "data") as! NSArray
            for i in 0..<data.count {
                let valueDict : NSDictionary = data[i] as! NSDictionary
                let id = valueDict.object(forKey: "id") as! String
                print("the id value is \(id)")
                let name = valueDict.object(forKey: "name") as! String
                print("the name value is \(name)")

                let picDict = valueDict["picture"] as! NSDictionary
                let picData = picDict["data"] as! NSDictionary
                let picURL = picData.object(forKey: "url") as! String
                print("the url value is \(picURL)")

                self.facebookContacts.append(User(name: name, documentId: id))
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

            let friends = resultdict.object(forKey: "data") as! NSArray
            print("Found \(friends.count) friends")
        } else {
            print("Error Getting Friends \(String(describing: error))");
        }
    })
    connection.start()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you can get the UID of your user based on their Facebook ID. It seems that you have two possibilities:

1. Search by email. This should allow you to pinpoint the person you are looking for.
2. Implement custom Facebook authentication. It requires a little extra work but is not too difficult to do.

Comment: I thought about the first option but I don't think you can grab facebook friends email addresses?  Even if they've given permission to the app

Comment: @pmanning probably not. In that case custom authentication is your only option. The benefit of it is that you can move the storage of FB data into your JWT endpoint. I mean that once the user logs in you can extract and put all the necessary data into database without having to do anything on the client side. If you are going to be implementing custom authentication do not forget that in Firebase you can declare functions which can be called via http ;)

Comment: @pmanning did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do the same.